# How to use metronic's bootstrap theme to other angular existing projects?

Tags: angular, metronic

I'am trying to figure out how to get just the design of the metronic i'm using, all i'm saying is i just wanted to get the html/css and paste it to other existing project.

Answer (score 0):

please floow the below steps

1) just go to the metronic website https://keenthemes.com/metronic/preview/demo1/index.html

2) select the button , dropdown or textbox  what ever you want .

3) copy the outer HTML of the element from mertonic site and  and paste it in your html code of your project .And reload it .

Comment: It's working but the codes are not readable when i tried to paste it from my actual project.

Comment: Do you have other alternative? Like when using CDN link rel(bootstrap) then just by adding a class name and it will show the design.

Comment: <li class="m-nav-sticky__item" data-toggle="m-tooltip" title="Purchase" data-placement="left">
  <a href="https://themeforest.net/item/metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/4021469?ref=keenthemes" >
   <i class="la la-cart-arrow-down"></i>
  </a>
 </li>